# Can I use a relative path to configure typescript sdk?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Can I set up typescript.tsdk relative to my project dir/tsconfig file? It looks like this option works only with an absolute path.

Answer (score 26):

In your project's `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Comment: I'm doing that in windows and it's not recognizing the settings.json from the workspace. I have previously npm install typescript

Answer (score 5):

You can set in setting.json like this:

```
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/bin"
```

But this break ts files that no have typescript installed by npm in root folder. The best solution I have found, was:

```
    "typescript.tsdk": "/Users/<MyUser>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/bin"
```

Still work on ts projects without typescript installed localy.

Comment: My current setting is `"typescript.tsdk": "C:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node_modules/typescript/lib"` until they [support](https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/Detail/17926) relative paths.