# VSCode: Is it possible to suppress experimental decorator warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript1.5

In VSCode, I get the error:

> "Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '`--experimentalDecorators`' to remove this warning."

I can add the `--experimentalDecorators` flag to my `tasks.json` file to remove this error on build, but I can't seem to remove it from my intellisense or error list when I load VSCode.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was having this same error. I added the following `tsconfig.json` file to my project root, restarted VSCode and it finally went away:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "ES6" 
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I've noticed that sometimes VS Code will not suppress this warning until you add a "files" array in your tsconfig.json, **even an empty one will work**. For me this has worked every single time now, if the message does not disappear, try the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ... 
    },
    "files": [],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Perhaps this will explain why everyone has mixed results?

Comment: I had the same experience but wasn't sure if it was due to the 0.7.0 update or that I hadn't tried the root folder. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Shouldn't the file be called jsconfig.json and not tsconfig.json?  Mine only worked with the JS instead of TS.

Comment: Could not make this to work with `tsconfig.json` and `jsconfig.json`... (v0.10.11 linux-x64)

Comment: no matter what setting i gave, it just wasn't going. had to go by @Wosi way

Comment: @Dimanoid if the error is in typescript is tsconfig.json and if its in javascript its jsconfig.json. Since the question specifies typescript the correct answer its tsconfig.

Comment: I am using VS Code 1.3.1, and adding `experimentalDecorators: true` to `tsconfig.json` still does not get rid of this error.  I am using typescript v1.8.10. other differences are `module: commonjs` and `target: es5`. Any ideas?

Comment: For me it was changing `"target": "es5"` to `"target": "ES6"` that resolved the issue.

Comment: Definitely help on the final version as well.

Comment: yea changing the tsconfig.json to jsconfig.json did the trick

Comment: Very nice! "files": [] // adding empty array solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: @JaneWayne I had problems with editing JS files, so worked for me only  when I put  `"allowJs": true` in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 34):

VSC is by default looking at its own TS library and definition. If you're using a different version (which is very likely) you should point VSC to look for that versions definition.

In my `settings.json` file, i have the following set up:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib"

}
```

I believe you can set this for either your User Settings or your Workspace Settings. So you can do a one time configuration in your User Settings or just for one project/workspace. This works if you have your typescript installed locally in the specified folder - which i believe is the default nodes module folder.

To edit your settings go to `File/Preferences/User Setting` or `File/Preference/Workspace Settings`.

UPDATE: Visual Studio Code just released a new version with better support for different versions of typescript. Check it out here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_languages

Comment: This works great! If you are experiencing this problem w/ angular-cli using webpack, give this a try. angular-cli is using TypeScript 2.0 locally. Create a .vscode directory in the root of your project and add a settings.json file with this snippet.

Comment: Thank you! This finally solved the problem for me. 
PS. Just make sure you providing a correct relative path, it starts from the dir you opened in VSC. For me its `"typescript.tsdk": "Apps/WebApp/node_modules/typescript/lib"`

Comment: Works great! You should mention that if you run a `npm list typescript` it will tell you how many versions you have installed, and if >1 you will need to 'tell it' explicitly which version to use.

Comment: Thanks dude. Works!

Answer (score 16):

I've to add the following in the settings.json file of vscode to remove the warning.

`"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true`

VSCode -> Preferences -> Settings

[image]

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, [edit] the answer and tailor the post to the question.

Comment: @Rob. Thanks for the info. Will do the same.

Comment: This worked for me. None of the previous answers did. Thank you @ManojPaul

Comment: This setting has been deprecated in favor of `js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators`.(2)

Answer (score 12):

You could do it the hard way by deleting the lines which create the error in `%code%\resources\app\plugins\vs.language.typescript\lib\tsserver.lib`.

Look for the following code and delete it

```
            if (!compilerOptions.experimentalDecorators) {
              error(node, ts.Diagnostics.Experimental_support_for_decorators_is_a_feature_that_is_subject_to_change_in_a_future_release_Specify_experimentalDecorators_to_remove_this_warning);
            }
```

Comment: for the latest version (0.10.11 at the moment) path changed to `resources/app/extensions/typescript/server/typescript/lib/tsserver.js`

Comment: I was also getting this error with a non-Visual Studio app (an angular app in javascript).  In this case the file to fix  is:    `node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js`

Comment: @people Also note that in my case, I had to replace multiple lines like the above in the file.

Comment: Just updated VSC; path changed now to: %code%\resources\app\extensions\typescript\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js

Comment: I've been fighting with this for 6 months now, have tried basically everything, and this is the only thing that's ever worked for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

Struggling with this across two different Angular 2 final release projects, this is my solution.

**tsconfig.json** in the **src** fold.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {

        "experimentalDecorators": true

    }
}
```

**AND**

Add this setting to File->Preferences->User settings

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib"
```

Comment: Only thing that worked for me out of all solutions on the internet, but I have to add it to settings.json which can be opened from workspace settings

Answer (score 6):

As other answers pointed out, your Visual Studio Code needs to find the `tsconfig.json` file.

I had the same problem. And it's mostly because I didn't realize the project structure.

**(Hint: Read the text from top to bottom in the picture below).**

[image: Solution]

1. I had confused the `tsconfig.json` with the `tsconfig.app.json`.
2. And I had opened the wrong folder in Visual Studio. As a result, the `tsconfig.json` was not in scope.

Simply opening the right root folder (i.e. the project folder, one level higher than the `src`.) solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for this one!! I was opening `src` folder with VS Code so all I had to do is copy `tsconfig.json` to `src`.

Comment: @MariusB actually, it's still better to open the folder one level higher, because you're not only missing out on the `tsconfig.json` but also on other files, such as the `package.json`, ... they all need to be in the root of your project. So, really, you don't want to open the `src` folder, but you actually want to open its parent.

Answer (score 4):

This helped me with React JS files (VSCode Version 1.9.1).

1) Put into `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

2) Restart VS Code.

**Note:** as Tim mentioned below, you need to add the `tsconfig.json` even if your not using TypeScript.

Source: https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-remove-experimentaldecorators-warning-in-vscode/

Comment: I've had success with this.  Note you need to add the tsconfig.json even if your not using TypeScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `"typescript.tsdk"` in `setting.json` to change specific folder path containing tsserver.js and lib.ts files used by VSCode.

See this example: [Can I use a relative path to configure typescript sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308050/can-i-use-a-relative-path-to-configure-typescript-sdk/32101636#32101636)

note: You find `setting.json` in File > Preferences > User Settings.

Comment: I had to edit the file the @Wosi way, **and** then edit "typescript.tsdk" to point to the directory of the updated file to get things working.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Grunt (grunt-ts), you must also add "**experimentalDecorators: true**" as option in the file **gruntfile.js** .

Your file should look something like this at the end:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    ts: {
      default : {
        src: ["**/*.ts", "!node_modules/**"]
      },
      options: {
        experimentalDecorators: true
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-ts");
  grunt.registerTask("default", ["ts"]);
};
```

For more information you can read documentation on github https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#experimentaldecorators

Answer (score 2):

In **Visual studio code 1.3.1** my fix is in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\typescript\server\typescript\lib\tsserver.js** and comment out or delete the line.

```
if (!compilerOptions.experimentalDecorators) {
     error(node, ts.Diagnostics.Experimental_support_for_decorators_is_a_feature_that_is_subject_to_change_in_a_future_release_Specify_experimentalDecorators_to_remove_this_warning);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having same error i figure it out as this was i name component file extension as .js it should be .ts

Comment: Are you sure? .js is JavaScript whereas .ts is TypeScript which gets compiled into JavaScript. In principle that's the same

Comment: @slfan yes they may be same but i notice that my file is written in typescript and i named it with .js ext which is wrong it will not compiled when you name it with.ts then it compiled into javascript

Answer (score 1):

Even when opening VSCode at the right level within your project you might still need an extra tsconfig file in your root. I now have a tsconfig in my project root (only containing php index and folders), ts folder (legacy typescript classes) and my src folder (vue components).

Don't forget to close the folder and to restart VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you oppened in your VS Code the folder of the entire project and not only the src folder, because if you open only the src, then ts.config.json file will not be in scope, and VS will not recognize the experimental decorators parameters.

In my case this fixed all the problem

Answer (score 0):

I already had experimental decorators enabled in tsconfig.json, so I was a bit baffled until I found [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9335) where someone says to check the settings in VS Code.

So I went to File --> Preferences --> Settings and searched for experimental decorators and checked both of these settings:
[image: experimental decorators enabled in settings]

Here are the details of my version of VSCode:

```
Version: 1.52.1 (user setup)
Commit: ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523
Date: 2020-12-16T16:34:46.910Z
Electron: 9.3.5
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Answer (score 0):

Below answer for VSCode version 1.60.12

1. press "ctrl" + ",".
2. type "settings.json".
3. [see this image to click on settings..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtoza.png)
4. paste "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators":true -->
   [See my settings for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BykQ.png)