# Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular-seed

I just cloned angular2-seed project from github and followed the steps, but i got this warning into VS code
[ts] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release.
Set the 'Exxperimentaldecorators' option to remove this warning.

Comment: This is a question and answer site...what's the question?

Comment: There is something not working with my VS code and typescript

Comment: I get this error with [js] instead of [ts].  WTF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode: Is it possible to suppress experimental decorator warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737677/vscode-is-it-possible-to-suppress-experimental-decorator-warnings)

Answer (score 20):

I had that issue when using @Injectable() on a new service that I created.
I had that warning from VS Code's typescript compiler.

The warning disappeared when I added that new service as a provider to the module where I intended to use it.

Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: Same here. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 20):

In Visual Studio code go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings` and check `Experimental Decorators`

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Go to File/preference/user settings in vscode, put this code

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Comment: Currently the settings file is at: C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

Answer (score 6):

In your `tsconfig.json` file, add your project's path to the `include` property like this:

```
"include": [
    "app/**/*"
]
```

Or alternatively you can add individual files to the `files` property. Here is what my `tsconfig.json` looks like as an example (for an Angular2 app):

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "removeComments": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/main.ts",
        "app/app.module.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "app/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "build",
        "app/main.aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: "include": [
    "app/**/*"
]

Comment: The `exclude` option helped me

Answer (score 2):

Your tsconfig.json should be like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "files": [],     //add a "files" array (in my case empty)
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Alternatively you can add a line in VSCode preferences (user settings)

```
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true
```

Comment: `javascript.implicit...` did not solve the issue for me, nor did eexperimentalDecorators added to compilerOptions

Comment: what does the addition of "files" do?

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code settings find "experimentalDecorators". This will list Extension->TypeScript with a property JavaScript-> Implicit Project Config -> Experimental Decorators enable this setting will resolve warrning

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code, open `settings.json` and add this line:

`"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true`

Answer (score 0):

I get this warning in VS Code on newly added classes. Project compiles without any errors. When I start to reference the newly added class via `import` the warning diappears.

There is no need to change configuration in VS Code or Typescript in such case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem using a command like this

```
tsc .\app.ts --experimentalDecorators --target es6
```

where .\app.ts is the path of the file

Answer (score -1):

It is due to the use of older version of typescript. You must upgrade your typescript version to remove this message.

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Also you need to upgrade your npm to latest version as well.

Comment: I already have the latest version of typescript (2.0.3), I just upgraded npm but nothing has changed