# Experimental decorators warning VSCODE

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular2-cli

I'm working on an Angular2-Typescript application. I've generated the project with angular-cli as follows:

```
ng new myApp
```

but when I create a new component, a warning appears on @Component tag.

I've tried to solve following this post:

[Experimental decorators warning in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271273/experimental-decorators-warning-in-visual-studio-code)

but does not work for me.

I attach my tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
"mapRoot": "./",
"module": "es6",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es6",
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
  ]
 }
}
```

Typescript version is : "typescript": "2.0.2"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode: Is it possible to supress experimental decorator warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737677/vscode-is-it-possible-to-supress-experimental-decorator-warnings)

Comment: @Wosi not works for me :(

Comment: None of these answers? Did you give the first three answers a chance?

Comment: This one works as long as you have TypeScript installed as part of your dependencies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38970591/616304

Also, try specifying TypeScript 2.0.0 exactly as opposed to ^2.0.3

Comment: @StephenWilson if I use TypeScript 2.0.0 version I get the following error when I try to do `ng serve`:
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'directoryExists' of undefined

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?  If so try adding "awesome-typescript-loader": "2.2.1" to your package.json and re-run an npm install

Comment: I use to get the error all the time with VSCode (only with projects where the tsconfig wasn't at the root of the project). Maybe in the last few weeks after accepting all the automatic updates, the problem finally went away. Maybe you just need an upgrade :-)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my problem as follows:

First, updating typescript version:

```
$ npm install typescript@next
```

and then, editing user preference in vscode, adding the following:

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Thanks to [peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet) :)

Comment: Explanation: You have to instruct your *VSCode* to use a TypeScript lib out of your *node* dependencies - not the built-it one.