# How take out "Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time" message

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

Basically, I have followed
[VSCode: Is it possible to supress experimental decorator warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737677/vscode-is-it-possible-to-supress-experimental-decorator-warnings) in order to take such message out but no effect has been produced.

Firstly, I was receiving this message:

> "(node:15077) DeprecationWarning: node --debug is deprecated. Please use node --inspect instead". I read somewhere to add "protocol": "auto" in launch.json (honestly, I have no idea what I have setup to automatic).

It changed the warning mentioned in this topic. Well, I have added jsconfig.json to the project root but it seems not change anything.

I don't know if it is relevant but I noted that Visual Studio Code About points to Node 6.5.0 while my local Node is 7.7.4.

At last, but not least, what does such warning mean?

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server.js",
            "protocol": "auto"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "ES6" 
    },
    "files": []
}
```

Debian shell

```
demetrio@nodejs ~/tool/elasticsearch-head $ node -v
v7.7.4
```

Visual Studio Code About:

```
Version 1.10.2
Commit 8076a19fdcab7e1fc1707952d652f0bb6c6db331
Date 2017-03-08T14:00:46.854Z
Shell 1.4.6
Renderer 53.0.2785.143
Node 6.5.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Setting the protocol in the launch configuration is telling visual studio code which debugger to use.
The original debugger can be specified using:

`'protocol': 'legacy'`

The newer debugger can be specified using:

`'protocol': 'inspector'`

And finally the option:

`'protocol': 'auto'`

allows visual studio code to decided which debugger to use. It looks like with the Feb release of code (1.10) it used the newer one for node versions >=6.9. For the March release of code (1.11) it uses the newer one only for node versions 8.x.

See the following links for more information about the two different debuggers:

[Feb 1.10 release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_node2-transitioning)

[March 1.11 release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_11#_debugging)

It is the newer debugger which is causing this message. Either specify you want the legacy debugger, or upgrade your code to version 1.11 (and use node < v8) to remove it.