# Typescript 2.0 @types not automatically referenced

Tags: typescript

using TS 2.0 Beta I can't get the new @types working. somewhere in my code:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

TS 2.0 @types:

```
npm install --save @types/angular
tsc
```

the compiler doesn't find the d.ts files though:
Error:(1, 26) TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'.

no issues with current (old) method of using the typings tool and global (before ambient) dependencies.

I expected the d.ts lookup to work automatically with 2.0 as described here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: Running into the same issue, wondering if this didn't make it into the 2.0 beta release? Didn't see it mentioned in the wiki or their blog article. :/

Comment: What editor are you using by the way? In vscode for example this is still a bug for example. Apparently tsc should work fine, it's just your editor that's complaining.

Comment: I am using the command line and local tsc direclty to rule out any issues related to IDEA

Comment: Have you checked that you have actually updated the globally installed `typescript` with `tsc --version`?

Comment: Regarding the editor you can configure VSCode to use your locally installed version of the compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32160966/6409

Comment: I've got this issue too, my project builds fine on my Mac but on Windows with exactly the same NPM packages installed it complains that it can't find one (out of 10) packages under @types. It's driving me crazy and I can't find any official acknowledgement of this bug, the documentation explicitly says - "By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation"

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same issue with another file - tsc didn't find node_modules/@types/es6-shim. Explicitly adding types to tsconfig.json helped:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmit": true,
    "types":["es6-shim"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

Comment: `"types":["es6-shim"],` doesn't fix the issue for me, the same goes for `"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types/" ],`. It still complains about not finding globals and other types which I usually reference

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, where it would build successfully via cli, `tsc app.ts`, but gulp build would fail. In my case, I needed to make sure the gulp modules were using the latest typescript version for compilation, not the version bundled with the module, i.e. for `tsify`, passing in reference to newer compiler: `.plugin(tsify, {typescript: require('typescript')})`.

Not sure if this applies to your situation.

Comment: indeed the problem seems to be in tsc I am not using anything on top of it

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing in Visual Studio Code is that a triple-slash reference is still needed.  The types compiler option in tsconfig.json will resolve compilation errors, but VS Code does not pick up on this, and it will show errors when you open the file in the editor.

Here is an example of a triple-slash reference for node:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts" />
```

The triple-slash reference can be in a separate file, and it will apply across the board to other files in the project, but it has to be in the same folder as the tsconfig.json file.