# How to automatically add types declaration for a library to tsconfig.json in TypeScript 2.0?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

[TypeScript 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/) comes with a new way of fetching type declarations using npm packages under the @types scope.

```
npm i --save-dev @types/lodash
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38535533/4131237), one can tell TypeScript where to look for TypeScript type declaration files by adding a string to the `typings` property of `tsconfig.json`, which is also documented [here](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["lodash"]
  }
}
```

It seems tedious to have to manually edit `tsconfig.json` every time I install a new type declaration. Is there a way to do this automatically?

I was thinking of writing an npm script for it but I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to using bash to edit a JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the new `@Types` definitions, you can simply add the `typeRoots` option and specify the folder.  i.e. `"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]`.  It will parse through that folder and pick up all the types you have installed, and you don't have to add the `///` reference

Comment: I'm doing that, and still having the same problem. VSCode doesn't recognize jasmine types, even when the node_modules/@types/jasmine folder exists, and typeRoots is in my tsconfig.json file

Comment: I've got the same issue. VSCode has an open issue for it at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11620