# Invalid 'reference' directive syntax error when referencing angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have upgraded to Typescript 2.0.3 yesterday and updated the reference path to

```
/// <reference types="angular" />
```

after installing the typings for Angular 1.5x using the following command

```
npm install -s @types/angular
```

I get the error when I build the project and the error doesn't go away.

> Invalid 'reference' directive syntax

How does one fix this?

```
/// <reference types="angular" />
/// <reference types="d3" />

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('charts', []);

    app.controller('mainCtrl', function mainCtrl($scope, appService) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        vm.data2 = [4, 5, 7, 11];
        vm.update = function (d, i) {
            vm.data1 = appService.GetRandomData();
            console.log('new data1', vm.data1);
        };

        vm.update2 = function (d, i) {
            vm.data2 = appService.GetRandomData();
            console.log('new data2', vm.data2);
        };
    });

    app.directive('barChart', function ($timeout) {
        var chart = d3.custom.barChart();
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            bindToController: {
                data: '=',
            },
            controller: 'mainCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var chartEl = d3.select(element[0]);

                chartEl.datum(ctrl.data).call(chart)
            }
        }
    });

    app.directive('chartForm', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: 'mainCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'chartform.html'
        }
    });

    app.service('appService', function () {
        this.GetRandomData = function () {
            var rdata;

            rdata = d3.range(~~(Math.random() * 50) + 1).map(function (d, i) {
                return ~~(Math.random() * 100);
            });

            return rdata;
        }
    });

} ());
```

Comment: Please post actual code, not pictures of it

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated the typescript path in workspace settings file `.vscode/settings.json` to point to the latest typescript version. This will make VS Code to use the latest version typescript.

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib"
}
```

I didn't assume this to be the problem because when I run `tsc -v` in the integrated terminal, I got `2.0.3`.

Now I am onto fixing the compiler errors.

Helpful links:

- [Can I use a relative path to configure typescript sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308050/can-i-use-a-relative-path-to-configure-typescript-sdk)
- ["Invalid 'reference' directive syntax" Typescript2 @types references](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9221#issuecomment-236901880)

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error in the build server, VSTS.

Upgrading the type script version resolved my issue.

In package,json: changed from

```
"typescript": "2.8.3"
```

to

```
 "typescript": "3.5.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the mac people out there, if you install TypeScript globally, your path looks like this:

```
  "typescript.tsdk": "/Users/me_me_me/.nvm/versions/node/VERSIION/bin/tsc"
```